# Blazor WebAssembly app /authentication/logout results in "There was an error trying to log you out: ''" fail

Tags: c#, identityserver4, logout, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I created a Blazor WebAssembly app and when clicking on the logout link `/authentication/logout` I get redirected to `/authentication/logout-failed?message=The%20logout%20was%20not%20initiated%20from%20within%20the%20page.` with the message:

> There was an error trying to log you out: ''

I'm using IdentityServer4.

How can I perform a proper logout and that I'm also logged out of the service providers (Facebook, Google and/or Microsoft)?

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
                {
                    facebookOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:ClientId"];
                    facebookOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:ClientSecret"];
                })
                .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
                {
                    googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                    googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
                })
                .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
                {
                    microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
                    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
                });

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the meanwhile I found the solution. In stead of directly linking to `/authentication/logout/` I use the `@onclick="BeginSignOut"` on the logout link/button.

Then you need to inject:

```cs
        [Inject] NavigationManager Navigation { get; set; }
        [Inject] SignOutSessionStateManager SignOutManager { get; set; }
```

and use it in:

```cs
        protected async Task BeginSignOut(MouseEventArgs args)
        {
            await SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();
            Navigation.NavigateTo("authentication/logout");
        }
```

Comment: Although this was already in the template, I still get the original error.

Comment: The SignOutSessionStateManager is obsolete, use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.NavigationManagerExtensions.NavigateToLogout(Navigation, "authentication/logout");

Comment: new way `NavigateToLogout` gives me an error when logging out on .net 8, old way (using `SignOutSessionStateManager`) works fine, so I think it's still in their template on purpose